# Windows batch script to replace a string

Tags: windows, batch-file, find, str-replace

I have a txt file that looks like this:

### file: config.txt

```
property name="java.nio.preferSelect" value="true"

property name="pico.rcp.platform.host" value="172.22.3.11"

property name="pico.rcp.platform.port" value="6790"
```

---

I want a windows batch script that will search for "pico.rcp.platform.host" string and change the IP value in that line regardless its value to the passed value in the command line. Like the following:

changeServerTo.bat "172.22.3.1" config.txt

the above script should make the file looks like this:

### file: config.txt

```
property name="java.nio.preferSelect" value="true"

property name="pico.rcp.platform.host" value="172.22.3.1"

property name="pico.rcp.platform.port" value="6790"
```

---

and

changeServerTo.bat "172.22.100.221" config.txt

should make the file looks like this:

### file: config.txt

```
property name="java.nio.preferSelect" value="true"

property name="pico.rcp.platform.host" value="172.22.100.221"

property name="pico.rcp.platform.port" value="6790"
```

---

and so on.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script just rewrites the entire file and uses the parameter in the output

```
echo property name="java.nio.preferSelect" value="true" >config.txt 
echo property name="pico.rcp.platform.host" value=%1 >>config.txt 
echo property name="pico.rcp.platform.port" value="6790" >>config.txt
```